# Finding VCI and VPI numbers remotely

Tags: networking, router, virtualization, path, isp

I am trying to connect to my ISP with a new router but after calling my ISP they say they don't know what my VCI and VPI numbers are. Is there a way of finding these out remotely?

The issue has been escalated to EE level 2 technical support, but the chap I spoke to on the phone said they are not able to provide these details because they don't have access to them. However, my new Belkin router gives the following message when connected to:

> **Do you have VPI/VCI numbers handy?**
>
> In order to get online, you need to enter the VPI and VCI numbers. They identify the communication path your ISP wants you to use.
>
> Your Internet Service Provider should have provided you with these numbers. If you can't find them, please call your ISP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### They are not able to provide these details because they don't have access to them

The EE support staff are clueless as usual. If they had searched for "VPI and VCI numbers ee" their own website is the first result returned.

> **Advanced internet settings**
>
> Virtual circuit:
>
> ```
> VPI=0
> VCI=38
> ```

Source [EE Home Broadband settings](https://ee.co.uk/help/mobile-and-home-connections/broadband-gallery-mobile-broadband/standard-broadband/setting-up-standard-broadband/ee-broadband-settings)

Comment: Ah ha! I found them myself at exactly the same point. Just checking if they are actually right as the numbers you posted appear to be from a forum, so not sure if they are accurate...

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter It's not a forum. It's the EE help pages https://ee.co.uk/help/mobile-and-home-connections/broadband-gallery-mobile-broadband/standard-broadband/setting-up-standard-broadband/ee-broadband-settings

Comment: Ah no problem. Now the dashed network protocols have deleted themselves again, and keep doing so each time Windows autofixes them! Will try again after a reboot. What a bother!

Comment: Yeah, every time I repair the network protocols they get deleted again so can't fully test your solution yet...

Comment: Won't attempt to connect via Ethernet either at the moment. Trying to install Belkin driver CD results on multiple errors. Trying alternative methodologies...

Comment: New Belkin router running incredibly hot. Turned off and back on again but still no connection screens...

Comment: OK, it's at least recognising the router again now. Let's try from here...

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Did you get it working?

Comment: I got past the VCI/VPI screen, but then it wanted a username an password, and even after confirming with the tech people close to a dozen times, it still wasn't accepted. Will just have to wait for the replacement EE one with the auto-settings. The VCI/VPI numbers do appear to be right, though, so I'll accept your answer now...

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter Thanks. Good luck with EE. I'm battling with them at the moment. They keep sending me multiple texts every day saying my data bundle has expired (it hasn't - although the old one has). 57 texts so far since 18/04 ...

Comment: Erk! Good luck! :/